# Alternative Ways In Adding New Rows in Datasource Data Grid View

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I'm creating a project in C# windows form. What I'm trying to do is add new rows in the datasource data grid view. But the problem is, the error says that adding new rows can't add programmatically in the datasource data grid.

Here's my method in fetching the data and transfer it in the data grid view.

```
public DataTable GetData(ClassName classVar){
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = ...; // My connection string
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = ...; // My Query

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table = ...ExeReader(cmd);
    return table;
}
```

The Codes inside my form

```
DataTable getDataTable;
getDataTable = ClassQuery.GetData(classVar);
dgv_details.DataSource = getDataTable;
```

And this is my add button

```
dgv_details.Rows.Add(txtBox1.Text,txtBox2.Text);
```

What are the alternative ways in adding data inside the datasourced datagridview?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add them to getDataTable?

Comment: add you new in the DataTable getDataTable

Comment: What do you mean @Dr.Stitch? I'm gonna add this code "dgv_details.Rows.Add()"?

Comment: like this getDataTable.Rows.Add(txtBox1.Text,txtBox2.Text);

Comment: The problem with that is, add new rows is after the datasource has been shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try the below code. First add row to datatable and then bind that table to datagridview.

```
  DataRow dr = datatable1.NewRow();
  dr[0] = "HAI"; // add data in first column of row
  datatable1.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0); // insert new row at position zero
  datatable1.Rows.Add(dr); // addnew row at last
```

Comment: The problem is, the add row will be after the datasource has been shown in the datagridview. So, the add NewRow will be not only one but multiple NewRow.